# Is the jupyterlab debugger available for notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html

Is there something I can do to have it installed when running `jupyter notebook` or is it necessary to switch to jupyterlab?

Comment: If you have any suggestions on how I can improve this question, please leave a comment

Comment: Why don't you ask developers? They have a meeting each Wednesday. See here https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab